# identify the element that slows down the dashboard refresh

Tags: reporting, dashboard, refresh

I have a dashboard that comprises 15 components. However, recently my dashboard is running very slowly, it takes over 5 minutes to refresh and this is consistent. As I check I have another dashboard that has the same amount of components but refreshes a lot faster (less than one minute). One difference is that the problem dashboard runs YTD reports whereas the good dashboard runs monthly reports. Is there a way of easily finding which component takes the longest and is the cause behind the delay in refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost answered your own question, reports that return more data will slow down the dashboard.

The most practical thing to do is to click on every component and identify which ones are taking longer to load.

Comment: I did try that after I posted my question but found nothing that was excessive, all were returning around 10,000-20,000 records and took less than 5 secs to run each.

Comment: If that's the case then it sounds like it is the sum of all the components what is causing this, consider reducing the number of components.